# Multi select dropdown list with a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

[How to add Multi select dropdown list with a button inside it to submit using javascript]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9B56.png

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the link below, hope your issue will be fixed.**

```
Click [here](https://codepen.io/souvik1809/pen/rvNMyO)!
```

Comment: Please consider adding some context to help the asker understand how this helps solve the problem.